# Finite Dimensional Vector Space Over a Field is a Noetherian and Artinian $F$-module

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, noetherian, artinian

I'm trying to prove that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field, $F$, then $V$ is a Noetherian and Artinian $F$-module.

I'm assuming I just have to prove that $V$ is Noetherian as an $F$-module, and then just switch all $\subseteq$ to $\supseteq$ for the Artinian proof.

I'm struggling as to how to get started with this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let be a increasing sequence of submodules( that is sub vector space) :

$V_1\subset V_2......$

But since V is finite dimensional vector space

$\bigcup V_i $

Is finite dimensional that is $\bigcup V_i =span\{v_1....v_n\}$

But since is a union there is for all $v_j$ an $V_{k_j}$ such that 
$v_j \in V_{k_j}$ let be $V_{max\{k_j\}}$ then

$\bigcup V_i=V_{max\{k_j\}}$

Therefore for all $n>max\{k_j\}$ $V_n=V_{max\{k_j\}}$

QED

For artinian is very similar

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Makes perfect sense. Thanks! :)

Comment: Looking back at line six, the wording doesn't quite make sense. What were you going for there?

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: "But since is a union there is for all $v_j$ an $V_{k_j}$ such that $v_j \in V_{k_j}$ let be $V_{\text{max}\{k_j\}}$". There might be a word or two missing in there.

Comment: Since the Union is equal to the span if we find a $V_j$ that include all the elements of the span the sequence stabilize so since is a union for all $v_j$ there is a $V_{k_j}$(by definition of the union ) such that $v_j \in V_{k_j}$  and since the sequence is increasing if you keep the elements of maximal index you will have the equality $V_{max\{k_j\}}=\bigcup V_j$